# External css and js not loading on android

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I'm running the HTML on android, chrome is not loading the external CSS and js files, all the files are in the same folder. [Repo](https://github.com/Coditdoc/Palindrome-Checker)

Beginner here.

**Html**

```
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Palindrome Checker</title>
             <link rel="stylesheet" href="/pali.css"> 
<!-- Before <link rel="stylesheet" href="pali.css">
also tried <link rel="stylesheet" href="./pali.css">  -->
      </head>
<body>
    <h1>Palindrome Checker</h1>
    <div class="main">
    <div class="holder">  
        <div class="bgimg">
        <span>Type in here-</span>
        <input type="text" name="textin" label ="textin" id="Udt1" placeholder="Eg-Racecar">
        <button class="btn" onclick="tex()">Check</button>
      
        </div>
    </div>

     <span class="anshold"><p id="udans">  </p>
         </span>
        </div>
</body>
<script src="/palindrome.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use ./ to your css link, not /,
ex:
./pali.css

Comment: Tried that also, but they are still not loading

Answer (score 0):

If the files are in the same folder like you said, the slash isn't necessary - simply `<link rel="stylesheet" href="pali.css">` and `<script src="palindrome.js"></script>`. If that doesn't work, I would also advise looking for spelling errors in the filenames.

Comment: It was like that, and files were still not loading I added the slash later, and no there are no spelling mistakes as everything is working perfectly on pc only issue is in android.

Comment: ah, then that seems like an issue with the browser and not the code itself.

Comment: Tried different browsers and different android phone too but nothing. Tried to find a solution on google still no help.

Comment: could you point me to your code repository? I can't help with much else without more information

Comment: hmm, thats super weird. its working fine for me on desktop. are you able to access the console output from your android browser?

Comment: js is not loading and hence acode is showing nothing in the console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245361/discussion-between-pufferfishe-and-coddein).